# Use of Global Variables in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

Why the value of variable is not changing while using `global` in function.

Am i missing something?

```
class testglobal():
    a=2
    print(a)

    def change():

        global a        
        a = 5

    change()
    print(a)
```

Comment: can you correct the indentation

Comment: What's the `class testGlobal:` for? This doesn't need to be in a class, Python isn't Java.

Comment: You don't need a outer class for this problem...

Comment: But, having defined a class, the initial `a` is *not* a global variable, it is a class attribute.

Comment: Although, since `change` is not decorated with `@staticmethod` and has no arguments, it can only be validly defined *outside* `testGlobal`, so it *does* create a global variable (and `testGlobal` is *completely* irrelevant to the call to `change`).

Comment: (Unless *everything* is defined in the body of the class, and the class itself is never used outside of being defined.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks didn't know the difference between global variable and variable in a class. I just have this one doubt then how will i change the value of a class variable inside a function?

Comment: @depperm Thanks for pointing the mistake

Answer (score 1):

To get your claimed output, your code would have to be indented like this:

```
class testGlobal:

    a=2
    print(a)

    def change():

        global a        
        a = 5

    change()
    print(a)
```

Both `print` statements are executed while the class is being defined, at which point both references to `a` refer to the *class* variable `a`, not the `global` variable `a` which `change` refers to.

---

If you are really interested in global variables, you don't need this class at all. Try the following code:

```
a = 2
print(a)
def change():
    global a
    a = 5
change()
print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the mistake. i want the output as 2 5. So how do i change the value of class variable inside a function?

Comment: Typically, you only ever define functions inside a class function; you don't call them. With this code, you can't; you would have to use `testGlobal.a` in the definition of `change`, except `testGlobal` doesn't exist yet when `change` is called.

Answer (score 0):

First: If your variable is inside a class, it's not a global variable.
You have to declare it outside of any function/method/class.
Second: The identation of your class is wrong. Inside a class, start with 4 spaces or a tab.